# How to hide part of a rails 3 form depending on value selected from dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a a partial, _form for one of my views in rails. It looks like so:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Project Status" %><br />
    <%= f.select :status, ["In Progress", "Cancelled"] %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Capital Cost" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :capital_cost %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

I'd like the "capital cost" part of the form to be greyed out unless "In Progress" is selected from the dropdown menu, without having to reload the page. Is this possible? I saw some solutions using javascript, but I'm a complete beginner and couldn't get my head around them (unfortunately I don't have the time to learn to use js before I have to finish this project). Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this you need some JavaScript. Use an `onchange` event handler to monitor the `<select>` input for changes. Compare the input value and conditionally set/unset a `disabled` attribute on the `#project_capital_cost` input. You can use jQuery for this.

By default, Rails 3 enables jQuery by including the `jquery_rails` gem in your Gemfile. Assuming you have `jquery_rails` included in your app and your `<select>` and `<input>` tags have `#project_status` and `#project_capital_cost` IDs respectively, add the following script into your `_form` partial with necessary modification:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     if($('#project_status').val() != "In Progress"){
        $("#project_capital_cost").attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
     else{
        $("#project_capital_cost").removeAttr('disabled');
     }

     $('#project_status').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "In Progress"){
          $("#project_capital_cost").attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        else{
          $("#project_capital_cost").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     })
  });

</script>
```

**EDIT:**

To hide `div` give some `id` to it:

```
  <div class="field" id="my_div">
    <%= f.label "Capital Cost" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :capital_cost %>
  </div>
```

Then replace

`$("#project_capital_cost").attr('disabled','disabled');` with `$("#my_div").css('display','none')`

and

`$("#project_capital_cost").removeAttr('disabled');` with `$("#my_div").css('display','block')` in script.

Comment: Nice answer, but i think removing the disabled attribute is better than setting it disabled. I had encountered to some issue with setting it false in some browsers so I like to remove it for the safer side. :)

Comment: edited answer to `removeAttr()`. It will remove attribute if present. Otherwise nothing will be done.

Comment: Cheers! Is there a way of hiding it also instead of disabling? Where do I put the <input> and <select> tags? Finally, can I put this in its own javascript file so it gets rendered into application.js?

Comment: Thanks @codeit - I'm trying both, but neither are working. From the source I see the <input> and <select> tags for the form inputs and dropdowns are given the id's "project_capital_cost" and "project_status" by default. I've put the script at the end of the _form, after <% end %>. It doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Figured it out - there was a typo on .change(function) - edited & fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

To grey out the input, use the HTML input tag attribute disabled.

```
<input disabled="disabled">
```

Which from Rails is

```
<%= f.text_field :capital_cost, :disabled => "disabled", :id => "capital_cost_input" %>
```

To enable it when "In Progress" is selected will require AJAX and Javascript, but there is some help from Rails.

First

```
<%= f.select :status, ["In Progress", "Cancelled"],
             {},
             "data-remote" => true, "data-url" => ..._path %>
```

This will set the onchange attribute for you and make the AJAX call.

Add a route to handle the AJAX call, and supply the URL for the "data-url".

In the view template for the AJAX action, write the Javascript to enable the input.
Something like

```
$('#capital_cost_input').removeAttr("disabled")
```

Comment: Don't ask *me* for more.  I fumble around with Javascript, and might not have this exactly right.  You can use the Javascript function alert to debug your Javascript.  Good luck.

Comment: why do you need ajax call and so for client side validations??

Comment: @codeit I understand the perspective.  You need to learn some Javascript to get this solution working, so why not just learn JS and skip the AJAX call.  Sure, makes a certain sense.  However, I'm a Ruby on Rails developer because I like Ruby better than C++, Java, and C#, so I'd like to code as much as possible in that framework.

Comment: @codeit I will further say that my apps usually make the definition of the behavior when a user makes a select data driven, so I have to get to the database to determine what to do.  That's not the case for this SO question, but this SO question specifically mentions lack of time to learn JS *right now*.

Comment: How ajax call will get the info of the select tag?? You are making things complicated unnecessarily. `I'd like to code as much as possible in that framework` for this I want to say: `JS` is also a part of `Rails`. It's not external thing.

Comment: When the behavior is data driven, then it has to be this complicated.  But I concede, for the SO question that is needlessly complicating things.

Comment: @KevL so heed codeit.  The solution I gave you goes through a lot of hoops to minimize the Javascript, and you still have to write a little.  All you really needed to do is set the on select and call a Javascript method.  It might be worth investing time in learning a little Javascript so when you encounter problems like this you can write it when you need it.